# I need to fill a temporary table partially from another table and the rest with static values

Tags: t-sql

I'm using TSql and I've created a temporary table with 23 columns. I need to fill the first 15 columns from another table and the last 8 columns with static values. The reason is because I an using Union in the final query to marry the temp table with the query data and that has 23 columns.

I used an inert into statement to fill the first 15 columns no problem but I can't figure out how to add the static columns.

```
create table #Inspections (CMPR_PKG_SQ int, 
    CREA_TMS datetime, 
    [SPEC_SQ] int, 
    [LOT_ID_TXT] varchar(50), 
    [SMPL_NUM] varchar(15), 
    [WPI_NUM] char(6), 
    [WPI_SEG_NUM] char(1), 
    [WP_PHAS_GRP_CD] char(1), 
    [WP_PHAS_TYP_CD] char(1), 
    [FINPROJ_SQ] char(2), 
    [MIX_DSGN_SQ] int, 
    [FCLTY_SQ] int, 
    District char(2), 
    [Mix #] char(280), 
    [Mix Type] char(128), 
    [3/8" Percent Passing] decimal(15,3), 
    [4 Percent Passing] decimal(15,3), 
    [8 Percent Passing] decimal(15,3), 
    [200 Percent Passing] decimal(15,3), 
    [Percent Content] decimal(15,3), 
    [Percent Voids] decimal(15,3), 
    [Density] decimal(15,3), 
    CF decimal(15,3))

insert into #Inspections (CMPR_PKG_SQ,
     CREA_TMS,
     [SPEC_SQ],
     [LOT_ID_TXT],
     [SMPL_NUM],
     [WPI_NUM],
     [WPI_SEG_NUM],
     [WP_PHAS_GRP_CD],
     [WP_PHAS_TYP_CD],
     [FINPROJ_SQ],
     [MIX_DSGN_SQ],
     [FCLTY_SQ],
     District,
     [Mix #],
     [Mix Type])
Select CMPR_PKG_SQ,
     CREA_TMS,
     [SPEC_SQ],
     [LOT_ID_TXT],
     [SMPL_NUM],
     [WPI_NUM],
     [WPI_SEG_NUM],
     [WP_PHAS_GRP_CD],
     [WP_PHAS_TYP_CD],
     [FINPROJ_SQ],
     [MIX_DSGN_SQ],
     [FCLTY_SQ],
     District,
     [Mix #],
     [Mix Type]
from SourceTable
```

How do I add N/A to the remaining columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide literals / constants in the select statement.

```
insert into #Inspections (CMPR_PKG_SQ,
     CREA_TMS,
     [SPEC_SQ],
     [LOT_ID_TXT],
     [SMPL_NUM],
     [WPI_NUM],
     [WPI_SEG_NUM],
     [WP_PHAS_GRP_CD],
     [WP_PHAS_TYP_CD],
     [FINPROJ_SQ],
     [MIX_DSGN_SQ],
     [FCLTY_SQ],
     District,
     [Mix #],
     [Mix Type],

     -- Additional columns...
     [3/8" Percent Passing])
Select CMPR_PKG_SQ,
     CREA_TMS,
     [SPEC_SQ],
     [LOT_ID_TXT],
     [SMPL_NUM],
     [WPI_NUM],
     [WPI_SEG_NUM],
     [WP_PHAS_GRP_CD],
     [WP_PHAS_TYP_CD],
     [FINPROJ_SQ],
     [MIX_DSGN_SQ],
     [FCLTY_SQ],
     District,
     [Mix #],
     [Mix Type],

     -- hard coded values
     19.783 AS [3/8" Percent Passing]
from SourceTable
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to insert 'NA' under the columns.

```
[3/8" Percent Passing],
[4 Percent Passing],
[8 Percent Passing],
[200 Percent Passing],
[Percent Content],
[Percent Voids],
[Density] &
CF decimal]
```

If this is correct, the query will not insert  because it is expecting a decimal (15,3), and you providing it String, i.e. 'NA'

Theoretically speaking this should work if attribute types were Varchars

```
insert into #Inspections (CMPR_PKG_SQ,
     CREA_TMS,
     [SPEC_SQ],
     [LOT_ID_TXT],
     [SMPL_NUM],
     [WPI_NUM],
     [WPI_SEG_NUM],
     [WP_PHAS_GRP_CD],
     [WP_PHAS_TYP_CD],
     [FINPROJ_SQ],
     [MIX_DSGN_SQ],
     [FCLTY_SQ],
     District,
     [Mix #],
     [Mix Type],
    'N/A'  as   [3/8" Percent Passing],
    'N/A'  as   [4 Percent Passing],
    'N/A'  as   [8 Percent Passing],
    'N/A'  as   [200 Percent Passing],
    'N/A'  as   [Percent Content],
    'N/A'  as   [Percent Voids],
    'N/A'  as   [Density],
    'N/A'  as   [CF decimal])
from SourceTable
```